# Weak convergence of cumulative distribution functions

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, weak-convergence

In probability theory in the definition of weak convergence we say that a sequence of Cumulative distribution functions $F_n(x)$ converge weakly to $F(x)$  `${\displaystyle F_{n}\left(x\right)\Rightarrow F\left(x\right)}$, if convergence happens for every point of continuity of function $F(x)$.

I am wondering if it is necessary for $F(x)$ to be a cumulative distribution function or not?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to talk about convergence of probability distributions, and weak convergence is a way to do this in terms of the cumulative distribution functions representing the probability distributions. There are more general approaches that aplly to probability distributions that are not just defined on the reals, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures). The definition can of course mechanically applied to other kind of functions, but what is the point?

Answer (score 2):

The pointwise convergence of $\left(F_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ in itself is not enough to guarantee that the limit is a cumulative distribution function. For example, let $F_n$ be defined by $F_n\left(t\right)=0$ if $t\lt n$ and $1$ otherwise. Then $F_n$ is the cumulative distribution function of a the probability distribution whose value is $n$ and $F_n(t)\to 0$ for all real number.

Therefore, the definition would not correspond to what we intend by weak convergence.